# Continuous functions that go from the rationals to the reals

Tags: real-analysis, connectedness

Are continuous functions from the rationals to the reals $f: \mathbb{Q} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ constant? I know that continuous functions $f: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{Q}$  have to be constant because of the Intermediate Value Theorem. However, I'm struggling to apply to the case where we send rationals to reals.

Comment: No. Any continuous function from $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ restricts to a continuous function from $\mathbb Q \to \mathbb R$.

Comment: @User8128 What do you mean by *restrict*?

Comment: The answer below explains what I mean. Any function on the reals can instead be considered a function on the rationals. If it was continuous as a function on the reals, it remains when it is considered a function on the rationals (assuming we use the subspace topology on the rationals).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Endow $\mathbb Q$ with the subspace topology (which I think is fairly natural.)

Then for any continuous function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$

$f^{-1}(V)=U$, when $V,U$ are open.

Hence $f \mid_{\mathbb Q}: \mathbb Q \to \mathbb R$ is perfectly well defined, and $f^{-1}(V):=U \cap \mathbb Q$ which is open by definition.

**Example: $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R: x \mapsto x$ is nonconstant.

Then define $f\mid_{\mathbb Q}:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R:x \to x$ is clearly continuous since $f^{-1}(V):=V \cap \mathbb Q$.

Comment: Would $f(x) = x$ be a counterexample? It sends rational numbers to rational numbers which are a set sub of the reals.

Comment: why is that relevant? The constant map $f: \mathbb Q \to  \mathbb R$ given by $x \mapsto 1$ function that sends rational numbers to a single number which is a subset of the reals.

Comment: Just wanted to understand it better. $f(x) = x$ is not a constant function but a continuous function that sends rationals to reals. It is also a good example to show that a function that can be applied to reals can also be applied to rationals.

Comment: well, yes. ${}{}$.